# Get attribute from html code block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read an attribute from an html code block. I have the following code:

```
$('#data').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
   console.log(e.target);
});
```

and my output from console:

[here](https://oi66.tinypic.com/2eo9yza.jpg)

I want to get the class attribute, in this example `repeater-row`. What method can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the class name of the added element (or classList if there are more than one classes for your li's). Documentation for element.className - here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

```
$('#data').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  var addedElement = e.target;
  var addedElementClass = addedElement.className;
   console.log(addedElementClass); // should give "repeater-row"
});
```